# Laravel - How to make different forms for the same api resource

Tags: php, laravel

Can I make different form for API Resource when I need a collection??

For example, if I have `UserResource` class
 and call `UserResource::collection`, I need only `id` and `email` columns.
But When I create `new UserResource`, I need all columns of users table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an option to treat the request accordingly.

Ex in your post, you add an input called

```
form_type = 'form1';
form_type = 'form2';
```

And in your controller, you just use this variable as required validate first and then, use it as you need...

Or you can do it with a route also... adding an argument `/{form_type}/`